Are toric codes (surface codes) doubly even, therefore have transversal $S$?
From this site and this post, doubly even codes have transversal $S$.
Based on this post, surface codes don't have transversal $S$ gates. We can check the boundary stabilizers of surface codes are not doubly even, so surface codes are generally not doubly even and don't have transversal $S$.
However, what if we go to the toric codes which seems to be doubly even? What's the logical effect of transversal $S$ gates?

The toric code is not in general doubly even. Take the $[[18,2,3]]$ code for example; $H_X$ has this weight distribution :
[ [ 0, 1 ], [ 4, 9 ], [ 6, 24 ], [ 8, 99 ], [ 10, 72 ], [ 12, 51 ] ]

1 element of weight 0, 9 elements of weight 4, 24 elements of weight 6,....
Since there are weights that are not multiples of 4, the code is not doubly even.

Sorry but I got lost: Are we checking every stabilizer element here? But It seems like that for CSS codes, doubly even only requires its stabilizer generators to be weight-4n (source: https://errorcorrectionzoo.org/c/quantum_divisible).

doubly even applies to all elements, not just the generators

Thank you and I also checked it through this paper. It seems like the ECzoo might need some correction there.

definitely ECzoo has it wrong
